# Не подключается самописная DLL С++ в скрипте ANSI-C SCADA системы WinCC

Tags: c++, c, delphi

Не могу подключить самописную DLL, созданную в C++, в скрипт ANSI-C SCADA системы WinCC от SIEMENS.

В качестве основы использовалась инструкция с [форума Siemens](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/8301801/how-can-you-incorporate-user-created-dlls-in-wincc?dti=0&lc=en-WW) (файл скачивается после регистрации, исходный код написан ниже). Там у людей тоже не получается.

На C++ в Visual Studio написана и скомпилирована простая DLL с исходным кодом:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int aufruf1 (int a);
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
FILE *h_test;
FILE *h_trace;
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int aufruf1(int a)
  {
  h_test= fopen ("C:/temp/test_dll.txt","a");
  if (h_test)
  {
    fprintf(h_test, "Function 'aufruf1' was called!\n");
    fclose (h_test );
  }
  a+=100;
  return a;
};
```

Пытаюсь подключить её и использовать в своем скрипте на ANSI-C Simatic WinCC, скрипт вызова функции DLL опять же из примера:

```
#include "apdefap.h"
void OnClick(char* lpszPictureName, char* lpszObjectName, char* lpszPropertyName)
{
  #pragma code ("c:/temp/T1_C.dll")
  int aufruf1(int a);
  #pragma code ()

  int value;
  value = GetTagDouble("var1"); //Return-Type: double
  SetTagDouble("result",aufruf1(value)); //Return-Type: BOOL
}
```

В результате в окне отладки WinCC появляется вот такое сообщение, что не получается найти вызываемую ссылку:

[Ошибка вызова функции http://www.imghost.in/img/2016-02/26/sb3iy865jz4lgho4gtotchnzv.png](http://www.imghost.in/img/2016-02/26/sb3iy865jz4lgho4gtotchnzv.png)

В то же время, с DLL, которая предоставляется SIEMENS все работает прекрасно. Вот [ссылка](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/attachments/8301801/t1_c.zip) на DLL (необходима регистрация). Стандартные Windows DLL тоже подключаются и работают без проблем.

**В чем может быть проблема, что я упускаю? Может кто-то подключал уже библиотеки C++ к ANSI-C. Может дело в Visual studio 2013? Ведь ветка форума Siemens всё таки 2008 года.**

P.s Самописные библиотеки на Delphi подключаются к ANSI-C в WinCC хорошо. Вот пример исходника на Delphi:

```
library Project2;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  WinSock,
  Classes,
  Dialogs;

Procedure ExplosionResultTest(incomeStruct : Pointer);  cdecl; export;
  var
    Server:TInaddr;
   inf: TWSADATA;
   z,socks: integer;
   sockaddr: TSockAddr;
  Begin

  .....

  end;

   exports ExplosionResultTest;

 begin
 end.
```

Вот так я её вызываю:

```
{
struct _myStruct myStruct;
struct _myStruct *linkStruct;

#pragma code("Delphidll.dll")
void __stdcall ExplosionResulTest(struct _myStruct *linkStruct);
#pragma code()

linkStruct = &myStruct;
ExplosionResultTest(linkStruct);
return 0;
}
```

Проблема, если я пытаюсь сделать DLL в C++ и потом её подключить.

Comment: Вполне возможно что дело в name mangling'е. Посмотрите на имена экспортов "хорошей" DLL и на имена экспортов вашей "плохой".

Comment: Первый исходный код и есть рабочая "хорошая" DLL, которая должна работать, только вот после компиляции ничего не работает. Так что не знаю что можно сравнивать.

Comment: Имена экспортов, а не исходный код. И в DLL, а не в исходном коде.